# Reading file into 2d char array works for 500 lines but not 50,000

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array

All I want to do is read the lines of a file into a 2d char array.  I've counted the lines and the number of chars in the longest line (using a function `lineCount()`).  In my first case, it was 500 lines of max 50 chars.  The second case is 50,000 lines of max 30 chars.  Here is my `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char fileName[] = "C:\\valid_50K.txt";

    int p[2] = { 0, 0 };
    lineCount(&fileName, &p);

    uint8_t** lines = (uint8_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*) * p[0]);
    for (int lnVar = 0; lnVar < p[0]; lnVar++)
    {
        lines[lnVar] = (uint8_t*)malloc(p[1] + 1);
    }

    readLines(&fileName, p[1], lines);   
}
```

and here is `readLines()`:

```
void readLines(char* fileName, int numChars, uint8_t** out)
{
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while (fgets(out[i], numChars + 1, fptr))
    {
        out[i][strlen(out[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

It works great for 500 lines, but with the 50K I get an error `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAAD21BC78 (ucrtbase.dll) in test.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal` on the `out[i][strlen(out[i]) - 1] = '\0';` line.  The entire file is only 1MB, with only ASCII characters, so I don't understand what the problem is.  I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: [mre] please. That is not a compilable program yet

Comment: Whenever I see the address-of operator for an array (like in `&fileName` *and* in `&p`) I see that as a red flag. The type of `&fileName` is `char (*)[18]`, not `char *`.

Comment: And of course you need to check the return value of `malloc`. Did it succeed in allocating that much memory?

Comment: `lineCount(&fileName, &p);` likely has weakness to it too.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: Definitely show us `lineCount `.  And **always** check the return value of `malloc`.  (This is just about an iron-clad rule.  Even if you're allocating 1 byte and it "can't possibly fail".  Even in a test program that you're going to run once and throw away.  *Always* check the return value of `malloc`.)

Answer (score 0):

> The entire file is only 1MB,
>   It works great for 500 lines, but with the 50K ...

Consider  a file of  49,999 lines of `'\n'` and 1 line of  (1MB-49,999) length will return { 50000, about 1MB } in `p[]`.  Code will then attempt to allocate `50000 * about 1MB` bytes or about 50 Gbytes.

Check return of `malloc()` to see if it is `NULL`.

---

`out[i][strlen(out[i]) - 1] = '\0';` is undefined behavior if the first character read in a line is a *null character*.

It is functionally questionable when a line does not contain an ending `'\n'`.

Suggest:

```
out[i][strcspn(out[i], "\n")] = '\0';
```